# Power Bi : visualization problem with year over year change

Tags: date, powerbi, visualization, period

I have created a visualization that gives me the percentage change in the number of sales from one year to the next.
This visualization varies according to a date filter.

I have data since March 1st 2021.

Here is my problem: If I filter on the period "January 1, 2022 to October 1, 2022" I have a problem with my visualization, it will be false because it will compare this period of 9 months with the same period in 2021, except that in 2021 I am missing 2 months (January and February 2021).

Do you know if it is possible to display nothing on this visualization if the filtered period starts before March 1st 2022?
I prefer to display nothing rather than a false value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think a solution here would be adding a parameter to the visual instead of a slicer.
With the formula if & else.